# How to read a value of file separate by tabs in Python?

Tags: python, string, text, readfile

I have a text file with this format

```
ConfigFile 1.1
;
;     Version: 4.0.32.1
;     Date="2021/04/08" Time="11:54:46" UTC="8"
;
Name
    John Legend
Type
    Student
Number
    s1054520
```

I would like to get the value of `Name` or `Type` or `Number`
How do I get it?
I tried with this method, but it does not solve my problem.

```
import re
f = open("Data.txt", "r")
file = f.read()
Name = re.findall("Name", file)
print(Name)
```

My expectation output is `John Legend`
Anyone can help me please. I really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: My guess would be to split by the lines, and loop through them, if you encounter `Name` print the next line and exit.

Comment: You could write a regex that would find the name entry in multiline-mode, but that file format seems like something that might have a dedicated parser already in existence (or perhaps you're expected to be writing it yourself). Parsing the file would be overkill for a very basic task of fetching just the name, but it might pay dividends if you need to do that *kind* of think a lot with other files with similar structure later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those label lines are in the sequence found in the file you
can simply scan for them:

```
labelList = ["Name","Type","Number"]
captures = dict()
with open("Data.txt","rt") as f:
    for label in labelList:
        while not f.readline().startswith(label):
            pass
        captures[label] = f.readline().strip()
for label in labelList:
    print(f"{label} : {captures[label]}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm going through each line and when I encounter `Name` I will add the next line (you can directly print too) to the result list:

```
import re


def print_hi(name):

    result = []
    regexp = re.compile(r'Name*')
    gotname = False;
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if gotname:
                result.append(line.strip())
                gotname = False
            match = regexp.match(line)
            if match:
                gotname = True

    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all `re.findall` is used to search for “all” occurrences that match a given pattern. So in your case. you are finding every "Name" in the file. Because that's what you are looking for.
On the other hand, the computer will not know the "John Legend" is the name. it will only know that's the line after the word "Name".
In your case I will suggest you can check this [link.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-specific-lines-from-a-file-in-python/)

1. Find the "Name"'s line number
2. Read the next line
3. Get the name without the white space
4. If there is more than 1 Name. this will work as well

the final code is like this

```
def search_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    """Search for the given string in file and return lines containing that string,
    along with line numbers"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            line_number += 1
            if string_to_search in line:
                # If yes, then add the line number & line as a tuple in the list
                list_of_results.append((line_number, line.rstrip()))
    # Return list of tuples containing line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results

file = open('Data.txt')
content = file.readlines()
matched_lines = search_string_in_file('Data.txt', 'Name')
print('Total Matched lines : ', len(matched_lines))
for i in matched_lines:
    print(content[i[0]].strip())
```

Comment: Thanks all for the advice. Really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regex, but rather make a parser for the file type. The rules might be:

1. The first line can be ignored
2. Any lines that start with `;` can be ignored.
3. Every line with no leading whitespace is a key
4. Every line with leading whitespace is a value belonging to the last
   key

I'd start with a generator that can return to you any unignored line:

```
def read_data_lines(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        # skip the first line
        f.readline()

        # read until no more lines
        while line := f.readline():
            # skip lines that start with ;
            if not line.startswith(";"):
                yield line
```

Then fill up a dict by following rules 3 and 4:

```
def parse_data_file(filename):
    data = {}
    key = None
    for line in read_data_lines(filename):
        # No starting whitespace makes this a key
        if not line.startswith(" "):
            key = line.strip()

        # Starting whitespace makes this a value for the last key
        else:
            data[key] = line.strip()

    return data
```

Now at this point you can parse the file and print whatever key you want:

```
data = parse_data_file("Data.txt")
print(data["Name"])
```